# frame of Root ViewController's View when loaded programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller

Im loading a root view controller in landscape mode at launch(no interface builders are used).
In viewDidLoad, I am adding subviews to root view controllers view, like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        // self.view.

    UIView *toolBar=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)]; 
    toolBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];

    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
//code contiues...
}
```

but self.view.frame.size.width returns width of portrait mode instead of landscape.

thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
[image: image for reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `-loadView` method:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}
```

Also normally the parent view controller is responsible for setting the frame size of its children view controllers views. In the case of the root view controller, I believe it takes the size of the UIWindow it's attached to (so if you set the window size in you app delegate, you can just use `[[UIView alloc] init]` and then set the autoresizing mask in the `-loadView` method).
You might need to take the status bar into account in the above code, depending on your own code.

Answer (score 0):

may be, portrait orientations are first in your project file (click to project in xcode, info tab in target, unit Supported interface orientations) ? If so, your app can launched in portrait orientation, then send viewDidLoad and rotate to landscape only after this.

Comment: I've already set supported orientations to landscape left and right & initial interface orientatio to landcape right in info.plist file. My application is launching in landscape mode no problem with it self.frame is returning portrait frame size instead of landscape framesize.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not use Interface Builder/xib files and neither create your view manually within `loadview`, the systems creates one with the maximum dimensions. This is stated in the `loadview` method documentation:

> If the view controller does not have an associated nib file, this
>   method creates a plain UIView object instead.

This system generated UIView object has a transform property that is not the identiy transformation and thus you are not allowed to rely on the values from the frame property as stated here:

[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIView)

> Warning: If this property is not the identity transform, the value of
>   the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

So, what should you to instead? I guess the best solution is to use the `bounds` property of you UIView. This contains the already rotated coordinates.